# Omit chaining parenthesis when using multiple Arel OR clauses

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

I'm attempting to abstract out a body of raw sql someone shoved in our codebase, and we're using Rails 4.2.8. I **want** to generate sql that ends with a where clause like so:

```
WHERE col1=1 OR col2=1 OR col3=1
```

I'm using the following Arel in an attempt to generate that sql:

```
my_clause = mytable[:col1].eq(1)
    .or(mytable[:col2].eq(1))
    .or(mytable[:col3].eq(1))
puts my_clause.to_sql
```

What I actually **get** is:

```
WHERE (col1=1 OR col2=1) OR col3=1
```

I realize that my code doesn't generate the word 'WHERE'. I added that in for the sake of clarity.

Our dba has been able to assure me that it's not a big deal in terms of performance, but it's triggering my OCD and I want to know what Arel syntax would I use to get the chained OR clauses w/o parens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to build the query you want with `Arel::Nodes::Or` directly (instead of `or` method that takes care of the parenthesis):

```
[
  mytable[:col1].eq(1), 
  mytable[:col2].eq(1), 
  mytable[:col3].eq(1)
].reduce {|clause, condition| 
  Arel::Nodes::Or.new(clause, condition) 
}
```